# Recursively determine if a set of numbers contains two subsets that equal in sum

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, sum, set

I need to figure out how to determine recursively if there is a selection of elements such that the sum of the selected elements is the same as the sum of unselected elements given a list of integers.

So for example the set
`nums = [1,3,5,3]` returns *true* because the subsets can be [3,3] and [1,5] that is both lists add up to 6, so the method should return *true*. If that subsets aren't present it should return *false*.

I have the code:

```
private static boolean canFind(int[] nums, int index, int sumOne, int sumTwo) {
    if (index == nums.length) {
        return false;
    }

    if (oneSum == twoSum) {
        return true;
    }

    if (oneSum < twoSum) {
        return canFind(nums, index + 1, sumOne + nums[index], sumTwo);
    }

    return canFind(nums, index + 1, sumOne, sumTwo + nums[index]);
}
```

but I can't figure out why this doesn't work, or even why it would.

Comment: Could you please show the splittable method and you have to edit your code too because of oneSum and twoSum is not declared, moreover I haven't seen any recursion in this code.

Comment: Hey there. I think your question could be made much more accurate if you asked it this way:

´Recursively determine if a set of numbers contains two subsets that equal in sum´

Comment: Sorry, the splittable method was re-named canFind (it's a recursive function, I just forgot to make that change. Will edit the question.

Comment: Can you provide example of how you input the code?

Comment: code is called from a public method with the same name:                             public static boolean canFind(int[] nums) {

  return canFind(nums, 0, 0, 0); <-- this calls the private canFind method
 }

Comment: What is the output you are looking for here?

Comment: @Rab it should just return true or false if it can find a possible solution

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to do or what the error you are having.

Comment: @Rab it's more that I just can't find out the algorithm. The idea is to see if there is a sublist of the elements that when added together is equal to the sublist of the remaining values.

Comment: Yeah I don't get what you are trying to say sorry dude.

Comment: @Rab that's okay I can't figure out any good way to word it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of the recursive `canFind()` method is:

- If I have processed the numbers up to position `index`, and have
  collected two sums `sumOne` and `sumTwo` so far, is it possible to
  find a solution with the remaining numbers?

Before looking at your code in detail, let's clarify the task a little more (if I understand it correctly): For a valid solution, each number has to be counted, either in `sumOne` or in `sumTwo`. Skipping a number or counting a number in both sums isn't allowed.

So, at any point in the solution process, you have the choice whether to add the current number in `sumOne`, or in `sumTwo`, and that's what you correctly do in the two recursive calls

```
    canFind(nums, index + 1, sumOne + nums[index], sumTwo)
```

and

```
    canFind(nums, index + 1, sumOne, sumTwo + nums[index])
```

But there's a problem around the calls. You can't know whether adding the current number to `sumOne` or `sumTwo` will be correct for the solution, so you should try both ways and return true if one of them succeeds. Your code adds to `sumOne` if that's smaller, otherwise to `sumTwo`. Although this seems plausible, it doesn't necessarily lead to the solution. So, you should change that part to read

```
    if (canFind(nums, index + 1, sumOne + nums[index], sumTwo)) {
        // if there's some solution by adding to sumOne, we're finished.
        return true;
    } else if (canFind(nums, index + 1, sumOne, sumTwo + nums[index])) {
        // if there's some solution by adding to sumTwo, we're finished.
        return true;
    } else {
        // if both tries didn't succeed, thre's no solution 
        // starting from the given situation
        return false;
    }
```

How long do we have to continue trying numbers? Until we get to the end of the array, as we're not allowed to leave out any number.

And when we reach the end of the array, do we have a solution or not? It's a solution if both sums are equal.

So, before trying the recursive calls, we should check for the end of the array:

```
    if (index == nums.length) {
        if (sumOne == sumTwo) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Putting it all together:

```
private static boolean canFind(int[] nums, int index, int sumOne, int sumTwo) {
    if (index == nums.length) {
        // if we're at the end of the array, we can compare the sums
        // to decide whether this is a solution.
        if (sumOne == sumTwo) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (canFind(nums, index + 1, sumOne + nums[index], sumTwo)) {
        // if there's some solution by adding to sumOne, we're finished.
        return true;
    } else if (canFind(nums, index + 1, sumOne, sumTwo + nums[index])) {
        // if there's some solution by adding to sumTwo, we're finished.
        return true;
    } else {
        // if both tries didn't succeed, thre's no solution 
        // starting from the given situation
        return false;
    }
}
```

This should basically do the job.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!